# Laravel lighthouse cannot use authorization on user model

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

user.graphql

```
createUser(input: CreateUserInput! @spread): User @field(resolver: "App\\GraphQL\\Mutations\\User\\Store") @can(ability: "create", injectArgs: true, model: "App\\Models\\User")
```

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
protected $policies = [
    User::class => UserPolicy::class,
];
```

UserPolicy.php

```
public function create(User $user, array $args)
{
    \Log::info($args);
    \Log::info($user->toArray());
    if ($user->hasPermissionTo(UserPermission::ADD_ACCOUNT)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

UserPolicy __construct function was triggered, but the create function is not triggered.

I got the error message "This action is unauthorized."

Is there any thing wrong in my code?

lighthouse version v5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm idiot. I forgot to pass the jwt token.